# Configure Windows Firewall Inbound Rule for Program Not Installed on Server

Tags: windows, firewalls

How can I configure an inbound rule on a Windows Server 2016 firewall to allow access from a program which is not installed on the server? When searching for a program browse is only offered for locations on the server. Is the path specified for the rule applied to the machine accessing the server? Is it possible to create a rule based only the executable program file name, irrespective of where it is installed on the machine accessing the server?

Comment: Not being rude but it looks like you don’t understand firewall config within windows at all. Sorry. It’s the wrong place to ask this type of question.

Comment: You want to be opening ports, forget executables. If it’s not installed

Comment: What program on the machine is *receiving* the connection? That's what you want to include.

Comment: Thanks - is there any way of identifying which program was making the connection?

Comment: What about using the command line: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule` for example `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow Skype" dir=in action=allow program="C:\program files\Skype\skype.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which network ports your application uses to communicate. Usually, firewalls do not support to choose some programs. The standard is to define source, destination and ports.